# No UI after installing Lion Skin Pack in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, user-interface

I have Windows 8.1. I installed Lion Skin Pack and after rebooting I see a black screen and no user interface. There's no explorer, no taskbar, no system tray, no nothing. Pressing the Windows button doesn't do anything.

Ctrl+Alt+Del works though. So I am able to open the task manager. By clicking the browse button in the "run a new task" window, I can browse the hard disk content. I can't open the control panel though and uninstall things.

I tried making a new user account from the command prompt, but I get the same issue even there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using a restoration point?

Comment: Those "skin transformation packs" usually change a lot of system files, and can mess the whole system up. See this article: [How to solve black screen problems after installing transformation packs](http://www.windowsxlive.net/tag/windows-8-transformation-pack/). In case you're unable to fix the issue, open a command prompt, and run this command: `sfc /scannow`. Report back the command output.